# Using vim.bo.filetype in an if statement to set filetype specific keybinds in neovim with init.lua

Tags: lua, neovim

I want to have a simple keymap that is only active when editing a C file using neovim.
This is the code in my init.lua file:

```lua
if vim.bo.filetype == 'c' then
    vim.api.nvim_set_keymap('i', '(', '(  )<left><left>', {noremap = true})
end
```

I was aiming for a simple `if=` statement to see if the file im in has the 'c' file extension, and if it does, 'enable' the keymap.
However, this does not seem to work

I am on Arch linux, using gcc as the c compiler (if that matters), and using neovim v0.9.1
[i have also tested the keymap by itself outside of the if statement and it works]

I am aware of this solution;

```lua
local function setup_c_mappings()
  vim.api.nvim_set_keymap('i', '(', '(  )<left><left>', {noremap = true})
end

-- Trigger setup_c_mappings when editing a C file
vim.cmd([[
  augroup CFileMappings
    autocmd!
    autocmd FileType c,cpp lua setup_c_mappings()
  augroup END
]])
```

However i was hoping for a more 'minimalistic'/simpler way of achieving the same result, hence the very basic 'if' statement

All of my research has people saying to use the above solution, but i am still hoping there might still be a way to use `if vim.bo.filetype == 'c'` solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, you want to put your filetype specific settings in `ftplugin/c.lua` and just put the single line
`vim.api.nvim_set_keymap('i', '(', '(  )<left><left>', {noremap = true})`. See `:h load-plugins`.

You may also want to look into `:h vim.keymap.set`

`init.lua` only runs when you start Neovim, but not when you open a buffer. You want to set the keymap every time you open a buffer with c file, hence the need for autocommands/ftplugin.

If you insist on using the `if vim.bo.filetype == 'c'` solution. You can create a autocommand that runs a function on every filetype with `BufEnter`, then do your logic in the function.

Note that you can create autocommand with lua api (see `:h api-autocmd`)